# Minified Sizzle

Tags: javascript, sizzle

I can't find minified sizzle =(
And if i trying to make it myself by yuicompressor, after that, some features not work.
Please help.

Answer (score 7):

Get the [latest uncompressed version here](https://raw.github.com/jquery/sizzle/master/sizzle.js) and compress it using any of these free tools:

- [JSCompress](http://jscompress.com/)
- [YUI Online version](http://www.refresh-sf.com/yui/) (Check minify only!)

The above are all paste/get result, not console applications, so pretty quick to get results.  The reason a minified version isn't maintained is it's not meant to be a standalone library, but rather integrated into whatever's using it...so the build processes/minification of the whole library, e.g. jQuery or Prototype 2.0 would include minifying Sizzle.

Comment: it is still havy after compressed. i heard it should be 4kb but it came out 17kb.

Comment: `VLead Compressor` link already cybersquatted (AKA broken).  The usual curse of all online tools.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the minifier at http://fmarcia.info/jsmin/test.html to minify it on your own.

Comment: It's work, and work with yuicompressor if i put --nomunge and --disable-optimizations.
But size + 4kb =(

Answer (score 0):

The sizzle website claims "Only 4KB minified and gzipped".
Most webservers serve the contents gzipped (transparently).

So I guess if you minify it, then your webserver serves it gzipped, then the transmission will only be 4K. You can probably check that with a packet capture tool (like wireshark). I don't think there is a way to include a gzipped script in your HTML sources, it has to be done at the server level.

Answer (score 0):

The basic function of Sizzle can be replicated as such:

```
function Sizzle(query){return document.querySelectorAll(query)}
```

All done. No need for library.